# Merging audio and video files of different length using mp4box

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4box

I have to merge video and audio file together. Currently I am using this command
`mp4box -flat -add <video> -add <audio> <outputfile>.mp4`
But the problem is, if the video is of say only 2 minutes and audio is of 5 mins, the video gets stuck at two minutes and audio plays till the last. I want to restrict the output to just 2mins.
I searched and found there is an option `-shortest` in `ffmpeg`. Is there a similar option in `mp4box`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MP4Box can limit the duration of the import. You can check:

```
MP4Box -h import
```

This will show the following option:

```
":dur=D"             imports only the first D seconds
```

You can use it as follows:

```
mp4box -add <video> -add <audio>:dur=120 <outputfile>.mp4
```

Note that I removed the `-flat` option as you probably want to have a progressive file, with audio and video interleaving.